# Proper way to keep app state in MVVM pattern in kotlin and Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

What is the proper way to keep the actual app state in MVVM? A simple example to describe what I mean: I have two fragments and one global variable or object of my Class. I can change this variable or object on both fragments. Where should I keep this in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easiest way is to use KTX extension function `activityViewModels<VM : ViewModel>` 
 see [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment).

From the doc:

> Returns a property delegate to access parent activity's ViewModel ...

It will retrieve the `ViewModel` instance provided by the `ViewModelProviders` of the activity the fragments are attached to. 
So any change on the view model instance will be reflected on all fragments.

Here a simple example:

```
class MVModel: ViewModel() {
    var count = MutableLiveData(0)

    fun increment() {
        count.value = count.value!!.plus(1)
    }
}
```

---

```
class MFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentMBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val viewModel by activityViewModels<MVModel>()
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this // <-- this enables MutableLiveData update the UI
        binding.vm = viewModel
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you correct me if I am wrong? So I have ViewModel to MainActivity. Next in both fragments I am using "function activityViewModels<ViewModel> " to get Parent ViewModel and then I can operate on this VM and change properties?

Comment: only call ```activityViewModels<MVModel>()``` on both fragments. As long as they are attached to the same activity, the changes made on one will be reflected to the other. If you want to access the ViewModel from the activity call ```val mvm by viewModels<MVModel>()```

Answer (score 0):

You can make shared view model where all your components will access easily

Comment: So I have to do one view model and attached it to both views? It doesn't matter that these two views are very different and have completely different functionality? It's the best way to do it?